# Clear contents of cells E through AN if cell E has contents

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear all of the contents from columns E through AN for only the rows that have data in Column E (and not continue through the rest of the sheet). I would like the formulas in the cells to stay intact.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
Sub ClearJEdetails()

    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("e12:AI1048530")
    
    'Selecting only hardcoded data
      rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
    
    Selection.ClearContents
    
End Sub

Sub ClearJEformulas()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("aj13:Ak1048530")
    
    'Selecting only formulas
      rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Select
    
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Use GoTo - SpecialCells?

Comment: You need to show us (copy/paste) the code you got so far so we can build on it. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71042473/edit) at any time.

Comment: I'm not sure they are the most elegant solutions, but i did this as 2 separate jobs:

Sub ClearJEdetails()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("e12:AI1048530")

'Selecting only hardcoded data
  rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select

Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
Sub ClearJEformulas()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("aj13:Ak1048530")

'Selecting only formulas
  rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Select

Selection.ClearContents

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

### Clear Contents of Filtered Rows in Certain Columns

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteFilteredEntireRows()

    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"        
    Const hRow As Long = 1
    Const lrCol As String = "E"
    Const Cols As String = "E:AN"
    Const Criteria As String = "<>" ' non-blanks
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = lRow - hRow + 1
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = ws.Cells(hRow, lrCol).Resize(rCount)
    Dim scdrg As Range: Set scdrg = scrg.Resize(rCount - 1).Offset(1)
    
    scrg.AutoFilter 1, Criteria
    Dim vcdrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vcdrg = scdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        
    If vcdrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Intersect(vcdrg.EntireRow, ws.Columns(Cols))
    
    drg.ClearContents
    
End Sub
```